# Why does "flag for attention" disappear after "show full answer" is clicked?

Tags: discussion, flags, review

I find it annoying that expanding a post on `/review` removes the flag link, forcing me to click through to the post in order to flag it. As a result, I usually ignore questions for which it's not clear from the extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to click through to the post.

When you show full answer, the  `link | edit | flag` links should show up.

Comment: Gar, how could I be that blind. Thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong!

`/review` isn't designed as a one-stop shop for flag submission. The "flag for attention" links are just a convenience for the blatant "HI I HAS PRBLM 2.any anser yet ne1???" posts.

Even if a post seems *kinda* flaggable from `/review`, you should always click through to see it in context. There are a lot of posts that contain non-obvious embedded links and/or that only appear valid after you see the questions they're attached to. One common one is "this is the right answer," which looks like a comment incorrectly posted as an answer at first, but is actually a link to a page that does answer the question.

Comment: I'm not blatantly flagging like that. An example of where it's not clear from the snippet, but is clear from the expanded post without context is when a user gives a long blurb about his experiences of the same (or related) problem and then asking for help with zero useful input. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229134/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method/5229748#5229748